# Kubernetes/Helm: When are ConfigMap functions called?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap, kubernetes-statefulset

If I have a ConfigMap like so:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: id-config
data:
  uuid: "{{ randAlphaNum 32 }}"
```

and a StatefulSet specification like so (taken and slightly modified from kubernetes' [StatefulSet Basics](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/) page):

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
spec:
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: registry.k8s.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      env:
      - name: UUID
        valueFrom:
          configMapKeyRef:
            name: id-config
            key: uuid
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: www
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Will `randAlphaNum` only be called once, when the initial deployment occurs, and then the value returned by `randAlphaNum` is stored in the `uuid` key and used if a pod restarts? Or will `randAlphaNum` be called every time a pod is created or restarted, with a different uuid being returned every time? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy something with Helm you need to differentiate between two distinct things that are happening:

1. Rendering the manifests, which happens locally on the machine where you execute the `helm` CLI.
2. Deploying the rendered manifests. I.e. sending the instruction to the Kubernetes API to deploy certain resources.

Entries in the manifest files such as `{{ randAlphaNum 32 }}` are rendered in step 1 and the pre-rendered results are sent to the Kubernetes API. It will only change if you ask Helm to render and deploy again.

Comment: So scaling down and back up wouldn't cause a re-rendering of `randAlphaNum`, but doing `helm uninstall nginx` and then `helm install nginx` would?

Comment: Yes, the only thing that will change that value is to trigger Helm to redo the rendering. Kubernetes doesn't know anything about it, it just receives declarative instructions which it executes

Comment: `helm upgrade` without uninstalling will cause the random value to change too; if you're using the `helm-diff` plugin, `helm diff` will always show a change; and so on.  But pure `kubectl` and other Kubernetes-API operations don't know where the ConfigMap content came from.

Comment: @DavidMaze yup. Adding `helm.sh/resource-policy: keep` as an annotation, and setting `immutable: true` seems to fix the value in place, even after uninstalling and reinstalling.

Helm outputs `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot patch "id-config" with kind ConfigMap: ConfigMap "id-config" is invalid: data: Forbidden: field is immutable when `immutable` is set`, but the deployment seems to go through just fine regardless.

Not ideal, but in the absence of what feels like a very obvious feature to have in helm, it might be a working solution.